# Why I can redeclare a property in subclasses?

Tags: objective-c

I put `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray arManagedObjectArray;` in subclass where in the parent class arManagedObjectArray is declared as NSArray.

However, I can do that.

If I declare @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray arManagedObjectArray; in the parent class instead, I will get a message saying that the property is not of the same type with the declaration?

Why I can do it in subclasses but can't do it it the parent class?

Comment: ? Is there a question ?

Answer (score 4):

> I put @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray arManagedObjectArray; in subclass where in the parent class arManagedObjectArray is declared as NSArray.

Remember your 6th grade geometry for a second, here.  Think back, particularly, to the groupings of shapes.  There's an axiom there that holds true now: "Every square is a rectangle, but not every rectangle is a square."  If you consider a square to be a subclass of a rectangle (which makes sense, because a square is a more specific type of a rectangle), then you can see the reasoning behind the Type-Theory flavored version of that quote: "Every S(ubtype) is a T(ype), but not every T(ype) is an S(ubtype).

If you think about in the context of this question, you get: "Every NSMutableArray is an NSArray, however not every NSArray is an NSMutableArray."  Therefore, you can redeclare properties of a superclass in a subclass, so long as the type of the property is equivalent to, or a subtype of, the superclass' property.  In that way, redeclaring an NSArray over an NSMutableArray always fails, but redeclaring an NSMutableArray over an NSArray always succeeds.

Comment: But I can't redeclare the property in the implementation of the superclass.

Comment: You can't declare properties in an `@implementation` block

Comment: I mean I can't redeclare the property in the extension of the .m file

Comment: if the extensions is named (@interface `NSObject (SomeExtension)`), then it's not possible to add properties or iVars.  You need an anonymous class extension (`@interface NSObject ()`)

Comment: I think I did that. Or did I? I should check again. Maybe I didn't do it on nameless extension.

Answer (score 1):

`arManagedObjectArray` declared as `NSMutableArray` in subcalss, when you acces `arManagedObjectArray` in subclass then you will access a `NSMutableArray`

and for accessing super class NSArray you need to write this

```
[super arManagedObjectArray];
```

and in super class you can access `NSArray`;

**Edit**

:

As per your question

you can not declare arManagedObjectArray as NSMutableArray in same class since you have this name for NSArray. So it is compile error, because when you call any method on arManagedObjectArray then hows compiler decide which array you need NSArray or NSMutableArray.